# Updating SQL Server databases

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am working on a project where data has to be updated across servers,  when ever a new update occurs in SQL Server, that update has to be replicated in another SQL Server.

At present it is done using web services.is there any open source tool like dts and ssis to do the same.

Is there any another better way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the servers up as linked servers you can do updates to both servers in the same procedure. The warning would be that linked servers can be a bit painful if any settings between the servers are different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Merge replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329%28v=sql.105%29.aspx was definitely built with this scenario in mind.  Not that difficult to use/setup either.